# How to Wild card the child nodes in Xpah match assertion using soap UI NG pro?

Tags: wildcard, soapui

I am looking to assert a particular attributes in XML using Xpath assertion and I don't need the child nodes to look for comparison. Currently, it is showing an error that " expected Exception:org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Diff [different] Expected presence of child nodes to be 'true' but was 'false' "

Any help would be great

Comment: Showing what you have do so far, would be great.

Comment: Having an example (what you trying)or screen shot or error details would help better to narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Actually now the above problem is fixed .. Am using ready api tool. My problem is am not getting the exact XML response as my web app in soap ui response..

Ex:

is my application response and

soap ui ng pro converts it as below

I understand that it trims the tag but it is causing issue during assertion.. Want to know how to get the exact response as application.. Please help